# mpi install from source, tar files

Tags: python, mpi, openmpi

I am installing mpi4py (following instructions here https://mpi4py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html) and because of restrictions in my environment I have to build MPI from sources (following instructions here https://mpi4py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/appendix.html#building-mpi).

Since I am quite new to this, where should the openmpi .tar file sit when I run these instructions and in what directory in command line should I be in when I run them?:

```
$ tar -zxf openmpi-X.X.X tar.gz
$ cd openmpi-X.X.X
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/openmpi
$ make all
$ make install
```

Does it matter where the .tar files are at all or does it matter where I run the tar command? I think I have encountered problems before based on where things were located so I just wanted to know exactly where to run this.

Comment: unless you are running as root, you would have to `sudo make install`

Comment: It does not matter where the `.tar` file is or even the extracted folder, the location where OpenMPI is installed is set by the `--prefix`. This is the only "important" location in the procedure. This location can be changed, e.g. to a separate install folder where you park all of you custom installations. But, the location has to be added / included in the $PATH variable or in this case $LD_LIBRARY_PATH as is described in the mpi4py installation guide you posted.
The `configure` and `make` commands you have to run in the openmpi-X.X.X folder